# Marklogic - flexible replication

Tags: marklogic

We've been trying to set up flexible replication in our system which uses a MarkLogic database. 
We followed the instructions from https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/flexrep/quick_start and have been able to set up flexible replication between two MarkLogic servers. We have verified that new documents created in the master are copied over to the replica. However, the master database currently has more than 47 million records that were there before we configured the replication. Once the replication process was triggered, we observed that the documents are being replicated to the replica very slowly. Roughly 20,000 documents were replicated within the first two hours. The rate is very slow, it would take months for the old records to be fully replicated.

Our questions are:

1. We are looking into increasing the hardware specs of the two servers, but aside from that would anyone have any advice or documentation as to how we could speed up the replication? I couldn't find any existing documentation regarding this?
2. Failing that, would it be possible to set up flexible replication without needing to replicate the initial data set? FYI, we also tried to clone the master database and use the clone as the replica. (We thought this might mean that the older records don't have to be replicated.) However, in this case we encountered XDMP-NEWSTAMP and XDMP-EXTIME errors on the replica server, so we gave up on this approach. A sample of the errors encountered on the replica is below:

> 2017-08-03 18:45:04.376 Notice: exp-rest-content-flexrep:
>   XDMP-NEWSTAMP: Timestamp too new for forest exp-rest-content-001-1
>   (15017569242290900) 2017-08-03 18:45:04.376 Notice:
>   exp-rest-content-flexrep: in /apply.xqy [1.0-ml] 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: XDMP-EXTIME: try { let
>   $raw-module-name := module-path($action-to-execute/p:module) let
>   $module-kind := module-kind($raw-module-name) let $module-name := if
>   ($module-kind = "xquery" or $module-kind = "javascript") then
>   $raw-module-name else $cpfi:xslt-action return if ($module-name = "")
>   then fn:error((), "CPF-ACTIONNOTFOUND", "Default success") else if
>   ($module-kind = "javascript") then (xdmp:trace("CPF Action Invoke",
>   fn:string-join(($caller, xdmp:get-current-user(), $uri,
>   $state-or-status, $raw-module-name), " ")), xdmp:invoke($module-name,
>   (fn:QName("","uri"), $uri, xs:QName("cpf:document-uri"), $uri,
>   fn:QName("","transition"), $chosen-transition,
>   options-var-js($action-to-execute)), $invoke-options)) else
>   (xdmp:trace("CPF Action Invoke", fn:string-join(($caller,
>   xdmp:get-current-user(), $uri, $state-or-status, $raw-module-name), "
>   ")), xdmp:invoke($module-name, ($vars, xs:QName("cpf:transition"),
>   $chosen-transition, options-var($action-to-execute), if ($module-kind
>   = "xslt") then (xs:QName("cpf:stylesheet-uri"), $raw-module-name) else ()), $invoke-options)) } catch ($e) { let $trace := let $context :=
>   fn:concat($caller, " ", $uri, " action failed") return
>   (cpf:log(fn:string-join(($context, $e/err:format-string), " "),
>   "error"), cpf:log(($context, $e), "fine")) let $failure-action :=
>   ($pipelines/p:failure-action)[1] let $raw-failure-module :=
>   module-path($failure-action/p:module) let $failure-kind :=
>   module-kind($raw-failure-module) let $failure-module := if
>   ($failure-kind = "xquery" or $failure-kind = "javascript") then
>   $raw-failure-module else $cpfi:xslt-action return if ($failure-module
>   = "") then fn:error((), "CPF-ACTIONNOTFOUND", "Default failure action") else xdmp:invoke($failure-module, ($vars,
>   xs:QName("cpf:transition"), $chosen-transition,
>   options-var($failure-action), xs:QName("cpf:exception"), $e, if
>   ($failure-kind = "xslt") then (xs:QName("cpf:stylesheet-uri"),
>   $raw-failure-module) else ()), $invoke-options) } -- Time limit
>   exceeded 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: in
>   /MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/internal-cpf.xqy, at 213:4, 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: in execute-action("on-state-enter",
>   "http://marklogic.com/states/initial", "/_smslogs/5849823.xml",
>   (xs:QName("trgr:uri"), "/_smslogs/5849823.xml",
>   xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...), different-transactiont...,
>   (fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/12349495875628658916.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/13179541037342910978.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   ...),
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[3]/p:default-action, fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[3])
>   [1.0-ml] 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $caller =
>   "on-state-enter" 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:
>   $state-or-status = "http://marklogic.com/states/initial" 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $uri = "/_smslogs/5849823.xml"
>   2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $vars =
>   (xs:QName("trgr:uri"), "/_smslogs/5849823.xml",
>   xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...) 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice:
>   TaskServer:   $invoke-options = different-transactiont...
>   2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $pipelines =
>   (fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/12349495875628658916.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/13179541037342910978.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   ...) 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $action-to-execute
>   = fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[3]/p:default-action 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $chosen-transition =
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[3]
>   2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $e = XDMP-NEWSTAMP 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: in
>   /MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/internal-cpf.xqy, at 342:6, 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: in
>   execute-transition("on-state-enter",
>   "http://marklogic.com/states/initial", "/_smslogs/5849823.xml",
>   (xs:QName("trgr:uri"), "/_smslogs/5849823.xml",
>   xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...), 6551367241994447650, (fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/12349495875628658916.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/13179541037342910978.xml")/p:pipeline,
>   ...),
>   (fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/12349495875628658916.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[2],
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/3358424510998587926.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[3],
>   fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/13179541037342910978.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[1],
>   ...), http://marklogic.com/states/initial)
>   [1.0-ml] 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $caller =
>   cpf:state("http://marklogic.com/states/initial") 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $state-or-status = () 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $uri = (xs:QName("trgr:uri"),
>   "/_smslogs/5849823.xml", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...) 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: in
>   /MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/internal-cpf.xqy, at 358:3, 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: in
>   int:execute-state-transition("on-state-enter",
>   cpf:state("http://marklogic.com/states/initial"),
>   "/_smslogs/5849823.xml", (xs:QName("trgr:uri"),
>   "/_smslogs/5849823.xml", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...), 6551367241994447650) [1.0-ml] 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $caller =
>   cpf:state("http://marklogic.com/states/initial") 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $state = () 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379
>   Notice: TaskServer:   $uri = (xs:QName("trgr:uri"),
>   "/_smslogs/5849823.xml", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...) 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: in
>   /MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/on-state-enter.xqy, at 41:6 [1.0-ml]
>   2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $state =
>   cpf:state("http://marklogic.com/states/initial") 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer:   $trace = () 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379
>   Notice: TaskServer:   $vars = (xs:QName("trgr:uri"),
>   "/_smslogs/5849823.xml", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...) 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: TaskServer: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: Timestamp too new for
>   forest exp-rest-content-001-1 (15017569242290900) 2017-08-03
>   18:45:04.379 Notice: exp-rest-content-flexrep: XDMP-NEWSTAMP:
>   Timestamp too new for forest exp-rest-content-001-1
>   (15017569242290900) 2017-08-03 18:45:04.379 Notice:
>   exp-rest-content-flexrep: in /apply.xqy [1.0-ml]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the instructions you referenced, it looks like you are using immediate replication, which will replicate any new/updated records in your database, but will not replicate existing records.

To enable replication of existing documents in the database (0 Day documents), you will need to change the replication setting from immediate push to scheduled task in the Flexible Replication Target configuration page ( **Databases > [database name] > Flexible Replication > Domain > [domain name] > [target name] : Summary** )

At the bottom of the page there you will see the ***immediate push*** option, which is *true* by default.  If you set it to **false**, then the replication will be handled by the push-local-forest process, and it will start to pickup the 0 Day documents.

As for increasing the rate at which documents will replicate from the source to the target, the primary setting is **Documents Per Batch**.  The guidance I've heard on this is to increase the value, while watching the execution time of the push-local-forest.xqy process ( **Configure > Groups > [group name] > Task Server: *Status*** and click *show more* button; or *http://servername:8002/dashboard* on the *Query Execution* tab).

Typically the *push-local-forest* process runs every minute, so you want to make sure that your batch size is optimized to be able to complete within that minute, otherwise you can run into situations where the next *push-local-forest* process will start before the first has finished, and they have the potential to start stacking up and dead locking.

Other tips for increasing the throughput is to reduce the number of indexes on the target (if possible), and/or use a VLAN with jumbo frames for the inter-cluster communication.

Comment: Immediate push was indeed set to true, but I'm confused. What I've observed is that after setting up the flexible replication, if I insert a new document into the master, the new document is successfully replicated to the replica, but afterwards it starts to slowly replicate the existing (0-day) documents. Is this the expected behavior or it shouldn't be happening?

I'll be trying to adjust the Documents per Batch. Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that it shouldn't replicate 0 day documents when immediate push is set to true.  It's possible there are some other processes that 'touch' the older documents, which will then mark them for replication, but outside of that, I'm not sure why you would see that behavior.

Comment: Hm, I see. Sorry, I know this is already outside the scope of the original question, but would you know a way to find out what other processes touch the 0-day documents? Or failing that, is there a query I could run to determine which documents the push-local-forests function considers as pending for replication? Thanks so much for your help!